# The 'cover' attribute has no file associated with it. Django

Tags: python, django

I want to display person pictures in a table with their name and surname columns. When i put as source static it show pictures but when i send request to database it didn't show. And its already insert data to database and  picture to `/media/images/`.

view.py:

```
def viewpost(request):
        person_list = Persona.objects.all()


        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('surname') and request.POST.get('address'):
                person = Persona()
                person.name = request.POST.get('name')
                person.surname = request.POST.get('surname')
                person.address = request.POST.get('address')
                person.age = request.POST.get('age')
                person.cover = request.FILES['cover']
                person.save()


                return HttpResponseRedirect('/viewpost')

        else:

            return render(request, 'mysite/viewpost.html', {'persons': person_list})
```

model.py:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    address = models.TextField()
    age = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

and template:

```
<td ><img src="{{person.cover.url}}" class="img-responsive" width="40px" id="pop" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></td>
```

Comment: Are you using django forms to save data?

Comment: Yes. And it save correctly in database.

Answer (score 1):

Without having settings and template code it´s difficult to get the whole picture, but here you have some tips:

To show static files in a template remember to use the `{% load static %}` tag.

Anyway, user uploaded files live better in a media folder, not in static. You should include it in your settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Comment: The're not static files. Every person in column have own cover(picture). And my settings.py already have those setting MEDIA.

Answer (score 0):

If problem is not solve. Try this.

in urls.py add this in bottom:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in html template

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```